# Start external process several times simultaneously

Tags: process

I need to start an external process (which is around 300MB large on its own) several times using System.Diagnostics.Process.

The only problem is: once the first instance starts, it generates temporary data in its base folder (where the application is located), so I can't just start another instance - it would corrupt the data of the first one and mess up everything.

I thought about temporarily copying the whole application folder programmatically, so that each instance has its own, but that doesn't feel right.

Could anybody help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try starting each copy in a different directory.

If the third-party app ignores the current directory, you could make a symlink to it in a different folder.  I'm not necessarily recommending that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an argument to your external process that specifies the temp folder to use.

Comment: I forgot to tell, that's not possible. It's some third-party software that is not configurable.